# How to add dictionary int values to existing int variables

Tags: c#, file, dictionary

In my program, I have some code that saves the player's records to a text file by organizing the data into a dictionary and on another play session, if the player wanted to load their pre existing data, they would type their name into the textbox, and if there is a set of data that matches the name, it would load the data back in.

The issue I have is that I am not sure if the code I currently have works. It says there are no errors, but I would like to check with people that have more experience to make sure I have the right set up. I have included both the file writer and the file reader methods below in case anybody wanted to see the file writer method.

```
private void FileWriter(string playername, int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties)
{
    var records = new Dictionary<string, (int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties)>
    {
        {playername, (playerwins, computerwins, ties)}
    };
    StreamWriter inputfile;
    inputfile = File.AppendText("Records.txt");
    inputfile.WriteLine(records);
    inputfile.Close();
}

private void FileReader(string playername, int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, (int, int, int)>> records)
{
    StreamReader outputfile;
    outputfile = File.OpenText("Records.txt");
    while (!outputfile.EndOfStream)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, (int, int, int)> res in records)
        {
            if (playername == res.Key)
            {
                playerwins +=playerwins;
                computerwins += computerwins;
                ties += ties;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there alway only 1 line in your Records.txt file. Am I interpreting this right? The Reader seems ok to me but the Writer is a bit of a mistery.

Comment: What happens whet there's no Records.txt?

Comment: No the reader is not ok either

Comment: Ok, I give up. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you think will happen in this line? _inputfile.WriteLine(records);_ If you think that this line writes the dictionary values into the file you are wrong. This line writes the class name of the variable _records_ because a dictionary has no way to transform its values in the string required by WriteLine.

Comment: You have the input vs output backwards.  Input is reading, output is writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some problems both in the FileWrite and in the FileReader methods.

In FileWriter you have an error in the line that writes to the file. Passing the *records* variable to *StreamWriter.WriteLine* will result in the class name written in the file, not the value of the elements stored in the dictionary.

```
private void FileWriter(string playername, int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties)
{
    var records = new Dictionary<string, (int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties)>
    {
        {playername, (playerwins, computerwins, ties)}
    };
    using StreamWriter inputfile = File.AppendText(@"Records.txt");

    // Get the first element in the array
    var kvp = records.ElementAt(0);

    // write the key and the values into the file.
    inputfile.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key},{kvp.Value.playerwins},{kvp.Value.computerwins},{kvp.Value.ties}");
}
```

Of course, this should be used just for an excercise because you don't really need to build a dictionary with a single element and then write the single element to disk. Just write directly the values passed to the method into the file.

The FileReader has a lot more problems. The code logic is not correct. You should first check of the Dictionary contains the playername then you could extract the KeyValuePair information using the array syntax. After that you could start the loop to read line by line until you find the player matching the key passed. At this point you can start the additions

```
private void FileReader(string playername, int playerwins, int computerwins, int ties, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, (int, int, int)>> records)
{
     
    // Check if the dictionary contains the player
    if(records.ContainsKey(playername))
    {
        // get the KeyValuePair entry for that player by the key
        var kvp = records[playername];
        using StreamReader outputfile = File.OpenText("Records.txt");
        while (!outputfile.EndOfStream)
        {
           // Read a line and splits its content in 4 parts
           string line = outputfile.ReadLine();
           var parts = line.Split(',');

           // If is the line that matches our key...
           if(parts[0] == playername)
           {
                // Do the additions.
                playerwins += Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value.playerwins);
                computerwins += Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value.computerwins);
                ties += Convert.ToInt32(kvp.Value.ties);

                // No sense to continue reading the file if we have found the player
                break;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

This FileReader still has problems. The variables passed here are local to this method and changing the values here makes no change to the variables passed into from the method caller. Also the *records* variable needs to be global to be used here. But this is material for another question/answer.